# How to convert a Map with Lists as values to an array [key1, value1.1, key1, value1.2 … keyM, valueM.N] using java-streams?

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream, data-conversion

Say you have a `Map<String, List<String>>` where the values are lists, e.g. `{{"a"->{1}, "b"->{2,3}}}`, how do you convert this to an array `["a", "1", "b", "2", "b", "3"]`?

I know it can be done with loops like below, but how to achieve it with java-streams?

```
public static String[] flattenMap(Map<String, List<String>> m) {

    List<String> flattened = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> e : m.entrySet()){
        for (String s: e.getValue())
        {
            flattened.add(e.getKey());
            flattened.add(s);
        }
    }

    return flattened.toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easily. `flatMap` is what you use to turn a single value in your stream into multiple values (and you want to map the single value of a `Map.Entry<String, List<String>>` into a ton of values). But it's even more complicated; you can't just flatMap x.getValue(), e.g. this: `m.entrySet().stream().flatMap(x -> x.getValue().stream())....` isn't going to do, that just gives you every value, not 'every value, with the key duplicated for every value). That's a flatmap in a flatmap, and would result in a harder to read code than the loop. It'll also be slower.

There's absolutely no reason to do this with streams. Hammers are great. Very useful tools. But if you have some butter you need to smear on your bread, maybe don't use the hammer :)

But, hey, I'm a fan of a feat of crazy same as the next fellow. So, in all its glory, here you go:

```
var m = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
m.put("a", List.of("b", "c"));
m.put("d", List.of("e"));
m.put("f", List.of("g", "h", "i"));

String[] res = m.entrySet().stream().flatMap(x -> 
    x.getValue().stream().flatMap(y -> Stream.of(x.getKey(), y))
).toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
```

> `[a, b, a, c, d, e, f, g, f, h, f, i]`